# Brute Force Algorithm for finding maximum independent vertex set in bipartite graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, big-o, bipartite

Does anyone know the the generic outline for the brute force algorithm for finding the maximum independent vertex set in a bipartite graph?

I know there are other algorithms such as König's Theorem for finding MIS, but I was wondering what the pseudocode for the brute force method would be?

In addition, what would be the run time complexity of such a brute force algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

The brute force algorithm is just to iterate over all sets of vertices and check if they are independent. There are `2^n` sets of vertices and iterating over all edges to check for independence is `O(m)`, so this costs `O(2^n*m)`.

Comment: What do the m and n represent, I assume m is the number of edges and n is the number of vertices?

Comment: If there are `2^n` subsets, then `n` must be the number of vertices. The maximum value of `m` is `n * (n -1) / 2`, hence the complexity as a functions of number vertices becomes `O(2^n * n * (n-1)/2)`